# Разворот Production-версии Rails приложения

Tags: ruby, vps, ruby-on-rails

**Доброго времени суток!**

До нынешнего момента никогда не занимался настройкой окружения для Rails-приложения. При разработки хватало Development && Test окружений. Но вот пришлось самостоятельно поднимать сервер с поддержкой Rails. Все вроде бы работает в Test окружении( на 3000 порту ), а вот Production версия не работает вовсе. 
Такой вот расклад: http://vm6277.vps.agava.net/. Я никогда ранее не поднимал сервера на Rails, в сети ничего толкового не нашел, поэтому прошу вас помочь, чем можете.

**Спасибо.**

Comment: А что пишет приложение в лог?

Comment: nginx + passenger ? Или вы запускаете RAILS_ENV=production rails s? :-)

Comment: @Vetal4eg, как ни странно, но в логах ничего. Даже лог-файл production-версии отсутствует вовсе.

---
@Чад, apache + passenger

Comment: В логах рельсов или апача?

Comment: в конфиге апача указываете DocumentRoot your-railsapp/public ?

Comment: Ради всего святого, только не apache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё зависит из под какого пользователя и как вы стартуете приложение.
В production режиме вам нужно чтобы приложение отвечало на портах 80 и 443 (SSL), но вы не станете запускать Rails приложение из под root'а, а для других пользователей эти порты не доступны. Так что ваш выход - это установка nginx.
А дальше уже ваш выбор - запускать ваш веб-сервер с проксированием через nginx через unix сокет или порт, или установка passenger.
Полно информации [вот здесь, Linode Library](https://library.linode.com/search?query=rails).

Comment: Спасибо! От этого можно оттолкнуться, чтобы запустить production-версию.

Answer (score -1):

Для начала, пробовали это ?

```
bundle install --without development test
bundle update
bundle install
а потом 
rake db:create RAILS_ENV=production
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```